# SELECT ... INTO variables set CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND to 1(TRUE)

Tags: sql, loops, database-cursor, select-into

SELECT ... INTO variables set CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND to 1(TRUE). This was discovered in 5.6.37 version. As example see next code.

```
DECLARE t_teil_sachnr, t_teil_alt CHAR(7);
DECLARE v_optm_id_sachnr, v_optm_id_alt INTEGER DEFAULT NULL;

DECLARE curs_done INTEGER DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE curs_Teilen CURSOR FOR SELECT teil_sachnr, teil_alt FROM my_table WHERE teil_alt <> '';
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET curs_done = TRUE;

#
OPEN curs_Teilen;

# 
loop_fill: LOOP
  FETCH curs_Teilen INTO t_teil_sachnr, t_teil_alt;
  IF curs_done THEN LEAVE loop_fill; END IF;

  SELECT id INTO v_optm_id_sachnr
    FROM optm_teil_alt_list
    WHERE teil_alt_list = '0000334'; # this SELECT script for exampl only

END LOOP loop_fill;
CLOSE curs_Teilen;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is enough to check the value of the parameter that the cursor returns. The parameter must be reliable, more precisely, always contain a value, and not contain NULL

*Instead of this check*

```
IF curs_done THEN LEAVE loop_fill; END IF;
```

*do this check*

```
IF ISNULL(t_teil_sachnr) THEN LEAVE loop_fill; END IF;
```